# Android Button doesn't update UI sometimes in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, user-interface, button, expandablelistview

I'm using Buttons in children of ExpandableListView.
I've added custom drawable to backgrounds of the buttons so that it can show another images per status.
It shows/update backgrounds of the buttons normally but sometimes it doesn't when buttons are pressed in a specific child.

Here is the drawable I use for button background.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_plus_highlight" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_plus_highlight" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_plus_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this parameter on ListView in XML

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

I hope this helps. :)